# GWT overlapping images

Tags: gwt

i have one window panel and i want to set image in it.so i do,

```
Window window = new Window();
Panel panel = new Panel();  
AbsolutePanel absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();    
Image image = new Image("img/heat_map.jpg");
absolutePanel.add(image);  
Image ap1Image = new Image("img/end.PNG");
ap1Image.getElement().getStyle().setMargin(1, Unit.PX);
absolutePanel.add(ap1Image);   
panel.add(absolutePanel);
window.add(panel);
```

but i stuck in code as i can't overlap another small icon image on main image(heat_map).
i want onclick event on that icon image.but i can't overlap images in window panel.please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you using something like GXT not pure GWT. But anyway - AbsolutePanel should implement something like add(Widget, int left, int top) method so you need use it instead of simple add(widget)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is in your code is you can not instantiate  GWT [Window](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html)  Class since the constructor `Window`() is not `visible`.

Second thing is there is no add method in `window class`.

And finally to overlap your images one on another you need to apply Some `CSS` 
(`Z-index..positions` )

[CSS Divs overlapping, how do I force one above the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354149/css-divs-overlapping-how-do-i-force-one-above-the-other)

And finally 
you can simply add a click handler to image.

```
imageIcon.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // Do something....
            }
        });
```

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for help.it's done as i use GXT and it has  add(Widget, int left, int top) method  of AbsolutePanel.